# In React Native how to navigate between screens?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation. I need to navigate from screen1 to screen2. I created tab navigation which include some screens but not screen1. When I click on a button from screen1 to go to screen2 which should show in tabbed screen, it is showing me error.

This is screen1(Main.js)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  ImageBackground,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Modal
} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Left, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Icon, Grid, Row, Button } from 'native-base';
import TabNav from '../screens/Dashboard';
import { Dashboard } from '../screens/Dashboard';

export default class Main extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
          <Grid>
            <Row size={2}>
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1,  justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
              <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <Button style={styles.buttonBrowseStyle} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}>
                  <Text>Browse</Text>
                </Button>
              </View>
            </View>
            </Row>
          </Grid>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

This is screen2(Dashboard.js)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator, TabBarBottom } from 'react-navigation';
import Post from './Post';

export const Dashboard = () => {
    return (<Text>Dashboard</Text>);
}

const TabNav = TabNavigator ({
    Dashboard: {
      screen: Dashboard,
    },
    Post: {
      screen: Post,
    },
  },
  { 
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    swipeEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: true,
    activeBackgroundColor: 'yellow',
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
    tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state;
      let iconName;
      if(routeName==='Main'){
  
      }
    }
  }
  );
  
export default TabNav;
```

Getting this error on clicking "Browse" button.

[image]

Comment: You don't seem to be using `TabNav` anywhere. Also, Main isn't in the navigation tree. I think you need to read the docs more closely.

Comment: @Kraylog I have inclided TabNav in my screen1(Main.js) but it does not provide any navigation props. I also don't want to mention my Main.js in TabNav since it will make a new tab with other tabs.

Comment: The navigation props are only provided to screens that are configured within the navigators. Since `Main` is not in any navigator, it doesn't get that prop. To solve this you have to reconsider the structure of your navigation tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the above answer mentioned, you are not including Main Component to your navigation so, you can basically think like they are not connected each other whatsoever.

What I suggest you is having a PrimaryNavigator, you can think as Main component in your case.

```js
const PrimaryNavigator = StackNavigator({
    SignInStack: {
        screen: SignInStackNavigator
    },
    SignUpStack: {
        screen: SignUpStackNavigator
    },
    DrawerMainStack: {
        screen: MenuDrawerStack
    }
},
    {
        headerMode: 'none'
    });
```

Next step, you can use your TabNavigator as in the below.

```js
const MenuDrawerStack = StackNavigator({
    DrawerBar: {
        screen: DrawerBar
    }
}, {
        style: {
            leftDrawerWidth: 40
        },
        index: 0,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#1874CD' },
            gesturesEnabled: false,
            headerLeft: <Icon
                name="menu"
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate({
                        key: null,
                        index: 0,
                        action: [
                            navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')
                        ]
                    })
                }}
            />
        }),
    })
```

And finally, you can build your tab navigator :

```js
const DrawerBar = DrawerNavigator({
    Shop: {
        screen: ShopTabNavigator
    },

}, {
        drawerPosition: 'left',
        headerMode: 'none',
        initialRouteName: 'Shop',
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'white' },
        }),
        contentComponent: props => <CustomDrawerMenu {...props} />,
        drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
        drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
        drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
    })
```

You should customize these but what I wanted to show you is that the methodology for navigation in React Native with react-navigation is pretty much like I showed you above.

And as the last part you have to pass PrimaryNavigator to your application as High Order Component.

```js
export default class Main extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <PrimaryNavigator />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Main should be part of StackNavigator. Navigation props is not available in Main because it is not a screen in any of the Navigator configuration.

Comment: I think you mean TabNavigator because I used Tab not Stack Navigator. And if I used Main screen in TabNavigator then how can I hide it from displaying in navigation bar. I do not want to show main screen in navigation bar.

Comment: That is why you should use StackNavigator. Put Screen 1 and Screen 2 (TabNav) in a StackNavigator to navigate back and forth between them.